# Error: "ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Private Sector/Self Employed' "

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

Output- "ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Private Sector/Self Employed' ".

I need help with this error as I get this error consistently

```
import numpy as np # linear algebra
import pandas as pd # data processing, CSV file I/O (e.g. pd.read_csv)
import os
    for dirname, _, filenames in os.walk('/kaggle/input'):
       for filename in filenames:
          print(os.path.join(dirname, filename))
    pd.options.mode.chained_assignment = None # disabled chaining errors as some columns overwritten below
    import sys
    print(sys.version)
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    %matplotlib inline
    from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
    from scipy.stats import levene
    import seaborn as sns
    from scipy.stats import shapiro
    from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split, cross_val_score
    from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
    from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
    from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
    from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB
    from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
    from sklearn.svm import SVC
    from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
    from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
    from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
    from sklearn.decomposition import KernelPCA
    
    
    dataset_df = pd.read_csv("TravelInsurancePrediction.csv")
    dataset = dataset_df.loc[:, ~dataset_df.columns.str.contains('^Unnamed')]
    
    X = dataset.iloc[:,:-1].values
    y = dataset.iloc[:, -1].values
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.25, random_state = 188)
    cKNN = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors = 10, metric = 'minkowski', p = 2).fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Comment: please share the full traceback including the line on which the error is caused

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your code and error, I assume that your data (either `X` or `y`) contains string values (e.g. `'Private Sector/Self Employed'` which you see here). The error tells you this and implies that you need to process your data so that it contains only numbers, since `KNeighborsClassifier` can't work with strings. Try to apply [feature encoding](https://medium.com/dwadda/ways-of-encoding-categorical-variables-b7a798931c8c).